# Error installing packages in RStudio: error reading from connection

Tags: r, rstudio

I have recently updated both R (version 3.4.1) and RStudio (version 1.0.143) and I am now unable to install packages from Rstudio.

If I install a package in R directly using `install.packages()` it works fine.

If I try and install a package in Rstudio using either `install.packages()` or using the package install menu I get the error below. I have tried a few different packages, and have uninstalled and reinstalled both R and RStudio.

To get the error:

**Run:**

```
install.packages("lme4")
```

**Output:**

```
Installing package into ‘E:/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘minqa’, ‘nloptr’, ‘RcppEigen’

Warning in install.packages :
lzma decoding result 10
Error in install.packages : error reading from connection
```

I am working off my personal computer, below is some of my system info:

**Output from**  `options("repos")`

```
$repos
                        CRAN                            CRANextra 
 "https://cran.stat.auckland.ac.nz/" "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin" 
 attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE
```

**Output from** `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.1252    
LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                         LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.1252    


attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1 tools_3.4.1
```

Comment: I got this error when my connection was interrupted. The easiest solution is to restart RStudio.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This certainly is an issue with your connection:the proxies you are using and repositories configured in your RStudio. I was getting the same error when I was connected to US VPN from India.I disconnected VPN and restarted RStudio and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue when I tried to install `caret`.

The best solution is to restart R studio.

Now the `install.packages()` works fine.

Answer (score 10):

Just restart the R studio it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after I misspelled a package name when trying to install it. I restarted R Studio and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly select appropriate CRAN mirror in R Studio through following option:
Tools>>>Packages>>>CRAN Mirror(Select appropriate CRAN depending on your location).

Comment: The CRAN mirror had been set as you can see in the output from `options("repos")`

Comment: @Finn, did you manage to solve the issue? I'm experiencing exactly same problem

Comment: @KasiaKulma I didn't, but a couple days latter it just worked by itself and I haven't had any problems since. A colleague suggested it may have just been a bug since both Rstudio and R had been updated at roughly the same time. I assumed a dev noticed the problem and patched it.... but obviously not if you are getting the problem. Sorry I can't be any help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to download manually the zip folder of the package and install it with the command  :

```
install.packages('package.zip', lib='destination_directory',repos = NULL)
```

- Package zip : the path to the zip file of the package
- Destination_directory: where the packages are installed by default  like *C:/Users/unknown/Documents/R/win-library/3.3*

Hope it helps

Comment: youd need to do that for all package dependencies