# What does it mean by R warning: "lzma decoding result 10" while installing packages?

Tags: r

- R version: 3.6.2
- Windows 10 x64

Recently, almost every time I use install.packages() there will be warning: lzma decoding result 10. The installation can be successful under this warning. But I want to know what does this warning means

Comment: Maybe you should reinstall Rtools?

Answer (score 0):

Is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867495/error-installing-packages-in-rstudio-error-reading-from-connection) of any help? In general, lzma is used to decompress the packages downloaded by install.packages. If R is able to overcome this, maybe decompressing them by other means, packages should be fine and you shouldn't worry about their functionality.